# 100% height div and margin with fixed header is actually not 100%

Tags: css, html, scroll, overflow

I am developping a web app for cross plateform mobile developpement (Cordova/HTML5/angularJS/CSS3).
I tried to have a header with a content scrollable (but no scrollbar over the header with using overflow:hidden (CSS) ).

`______________
|    HEADER    |
|--------------| 
|            |#|
|            |#|
|    Content |#|
|            |#|
|            |#|
|            |#|
|--------------| 
'#' = scrollbar`

so this is working but I can't scroll all the way down because a part of my content div is out of the screen at the bottom. This container div is 100% height (CSS) and margin-top of header height (CSS as well):

### here is the:

### **[CODE AND LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LKv49/5/)**

I did a fix with the JS but it's not the best solution to me (especially for mobile performances), CSS only should work !
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What's Going On

You'd like to have a container that is all of the page minus a set height, (from a header above it).

You can do with with CSS (No JS!) and with full old browser compatibility, just using `position`ing tricks.

First, set your `#globalWrapper` to `position:relative`, to catch anything that is `position`ed `absolute`ly inside it.

Next, set your `.ScrollableWrapper` to `position:absolute`, with `top:45px` (instead of `margin-top:45px`, and `left`, `right`, and `bottom` to `0`.

## Code

```
#globalWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position:relative;
}
.ScrollableWrapper {
    top: 45px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    border: 5px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Note, `.ScrollableWrapper` must NOT be set to `height:100%`.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKv49/11/)**

Comment: I've just edited my fiddle to use absolute positioning but you've already add the similar answer **but** your fiddle does not work because you have not removed all the script, you should remove the script in the demo.

Comment: Odd, it worked on my Firefox, even with the script. Removed though, good catch!

Comment: maybe the script did not run properly in FireFox :)

Comment: Perfetcly working I will test it on mobile devices but I'm confident :) Thanks a lot for your help !